# Joomla 4 CSP and SVGATOR

Tags: javascript, joomla, content-security-policy, joomla4, svgator

Created animated svgs in svgator (containing js)) which are being blocked by the CSP in Joomla 4.

Could anyone please assist in the correct settings for the System > HTML Headers plugin Content-Security-Policy (CSP) tab.

Thanks in advance!